# i'm having difficulties with if else

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement

Help, i have written a code, where it will detect an object position and do something according to the function, but i'm having a problem with the if else statement, the 2 last "else if" are for some reason not working

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);
function mainLoop (event:Event):void{
movePanel();
}
function movePanel():void{
Panel.x = 500;
if (panelIsClicked){
    Panel.startDrag();
}else{
    Panel.stopDrag();
}
if (Panel.y >= 1250){
    Panel.y = 1250;
}
if (Panel.y <= -730){
    Panel.y = -730;
}

if (Panel.y >= 770){
    Pager.Butt1.play();
    Pager.Butt2.gotoAndStop(1);
    Pager.Butt3.gotoAndStop(1);
    Pager.Butt4.gotoAndStop(1);
}
else if (170 < Panel.y <= 769){
    Pager.Butt2.play();
    Pager.Butt3.gotoAndStop(1);
    Pager.Butt1.gotoAndStop(1);
    Pager.Butt4.gotoAndStop(1);
}
else{
    Pager.Butt4.play();
    Pager.Butt1.gotoAndStop(1);
    Pager.Butt2.gotoAndStop(1);
    Pager.Butt3.gotoAndStop(1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've used a wrong syntax. Change this line:

```
else if (170 < Panel.y <= 769){
```

like this:

```
else if (170 < Panel.y && Panel.y <= 769){
```

and it'll work. Good luck!

Comment: Just to expand. `170 < Panel.y` will evaluate first, so it might end up trying to do something like `true <= 769`, which doesn't make sense.